# How can I change the stiffness of spring during analysis in Abaqus.?

Tags: subroutine, abaqus

For example, I have this statik system:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n96jq.jpg)

**My goal:**

*I want to investigate the behavior of the beam, when a stiffness of the spring is changed during analysis*

At the "Step-1" the system is loaded by means of concentrated load  "F".

**I want:**

At "Step-2" the system shall be loaded by means of same load "F", but the stiffness of spring shall be changed.

Because of, the spring is not a type of boundary conditions in Abaqus, I can't change the stiffness at "Step-2". I can change the stiffness after a "job" is finished. It means, that I have alwas a new system. I want to change the stiffness in already deformed system.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can define the dependency of spring stiffness on a field variable. Then controlling this variable will let you change the stiffness as needed.